# How to access models in PagesController--or how to create a dashboard with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, associations, models, dashboard

I have an order processing and catalog system created in CakePHP. It manages orders, products, packages, invoices, etc. (anything that would be necessary for an ecommerce store basically).

I now want to make a "dashboard"-type page, that will show the latest orders, products that need to be updated, latest reviews, etc. I was going to create a Page for PagesController, but I don't know how to access models in PagesController.

Is there any way to access several, unassociated models on one page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to build a “dashboard” for your application in CakePHP](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/12/16/how-to-build-a-dashboard-for-your-application-in-cakephp/).

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I think I'll create one controller used just for accessing multiple models. Because I may need this for my /cart also.

Answer (score 1):

> I was going to create a Page for PagesController, but I don't know how to access models in PagesController.

With the built-in PagesController, you can't. You'll have to create your own PagesController, which would look something like [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/qbfX9y0r).

Another way to create such a portal page would be to create a Page for display via the built-in PagesController, the view for which would comprise a variety of view elements, each using `requestAction` to retrieve their respective data. This can be a tricky approach if you don't or can't employ caching, because `requestAction` is not very performant, as it begins a new dispatch cycle every time it's called. However, in conjunction with good, aggressive caching, this is a very modular approach, and very Cake-y, since it encapsulates each element of your dashboard's functionality in its own MVC element.

**Edit**: just to be extra-clear, if you cannot cache the dashboard's elements well, you want to avoid the `requestAction` route. It's just horrifically slow, and it's better to use an approach such as that in balcer's link, though it is perhaps not as elegant.

Comment: thanks for the help, I like the looks of the link bancer provided